# Поиск всех страниц в папке сайта

Tags: парсер

Всем доброго вечера.

Есть такой музыкальный сервис, как Qobuz. Все его релизы хранятся в этой *папке*: https://open.qobuz.com/album/; Ссылка на релиз выглядит: https://open.qobuz.com/album/kn331n12xdhtb

Можно ли как-то получить все страницы в этой *папке*? В какую сторону копать и изучать вопрос?
Или это в целом невыполнимая задача и стоит идти другим путем?

Comment: Во-первых, это не папки. Во-вторых, если сам сервер нигде не отдаёт этот список, то нельзя

Comment: Списки [тут есть](https://www.qobuz.com/us-en/shop), и поиск там есть. Но что конкретно хочет @user557539 не понятно.